# Stripe API requires the POS registration code, where to find it?

Tags: stripe-payments

To use the Strip API I need the registration_code of my POS, which is a Wise Pad 3 actually.

I found nowhere that tell where I can fetch the `READER_REGISTRATION_CODE`.
Anyone knows?

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/terminal/readers \
  -u sk_test_51IlTKIECAWh7bkDyfLu...ZKDHzdNJv700BVcWRAK8sk_test_51IlTKIECAWh7bkDyfLu6jK4ABbE7dBgouHFolX9G6tLUNIeNvoXBaPCUB79oPcFKq27N2u0aRT0MSZZKDHzdNJv700BVcWRAK8: \
  -d "registration_code"="{{READER_REGISTRATION_CODE}}" \
  -d "label"="Alice's Reader" \
  -d "location"={{LOCATION_ID}}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You would only create the Reader if you are using the Server-driven integration which isn't supported for the WisePad 3. You need to use the Terminal iOS, Android, or React Native SDKs. I'd recommend reading through the relevant docs starting here: https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-integration?terminal-sdk-platform=ios